# Restricting access to a model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, scope

I'm building a small little CRM type app for my brother's company as a Laravel learning exercise. I really like what I've learned from this framework so far.

I have a `Deal` model that has a couple of boolean attributes, `for_management` and `for_admin`. My `User` model also has `is_management` and `is_admin` boolean attributes.

My main route to show the deals right now is returning all deals, but of course I want to only show the deals that are relevant to the user. A user might be both management and admin, so not sure of the best way to structure that logic.

Feels like I don't really want that logic to exist in the controller and might be better being defined in the `User`?

Scopes are another thing I've been looking at, but it doesn't feel like it would be "the right thing".

What would you suggest?

Comment: Did you define any kind of relationship between User and Deal models? A Deal can be owned by more than 1 User? Please elaborate and show your models definition or anything that help us to point you in the right way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.